# Use Siri To Launch App

Tags: ios, siri

I am trying to use Siri to launch an app.  So I say "Open Hipchat", however Siri interprets it as "Open Hip Chat".   Which she then doesn't find it because the app is named "HipChat" and not "Hip Chat".

Any way to help Siri understand that "Hipchat" is one word and not two?

Comment: What version of iOS are you running?

Comment: I was on 9.0 on a new iPhone 6S.   I upgraded to 9.0.1 this morning and it started working.  Don't know if it was the upgrade or just a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Siri finds hip chat for me on my iPad and iPhone.

The space doesn't matter.  I wonder if some other thing is wrong with your spotlight index, or if you've run out of free space on the device.

You might need to troubleshoot other apps and Siri or go through some of the generic troubleshooting steps like powering off the phone, restoring phone, etc.

Comment: Heck, even "Open chat" works for me. Color me surprised at siri's ability to figure out what I want done.

Comment: very strange that it works for you but not me.  Im on iOS 9.0